# Prioritize the records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has id and statement columns, statement column contains statement like insert into tablename, update tablename, delete tablename (tablename might be any xxx), I have a scenario where I need to write a stored procedure, if I run SP it should get the insert records in statement column first with parent tablenames first and then child table insert into statement and after inserts update statement should come in any fashion and at last delete statement with child table statement first and then parent.

Output should be like

```
statements
INSERT INTO country(parent to state)
INSERT INTO state(parent to city)
INSERT INTO city(parent to zipcode)
INSERT INTO zipcode
```

Comment: Do you want to call the same statement several times with different variables each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  to get your procedure done you must keep 1 more column like seqno int and update seqno with parent child levels . It will be very difficult  to read table names from the statement column and find the parent child levels from sql server 
 so i am assuming you are having seqno in that table  then u can write proc as following

```
 DECLARE @table table (statements varchar(200),id int,seqno int)
INSERT INTO @table 
values('INSERT INTO country(parent to state)',1,1),
 ('INSERT INTO state(parent to city)',2,2),
 ('INSERT INTO city(parent to zipcode)' ,3,3),
 ('INSERT INTO zipcode' ,4,4),
 ('update  city(parent to zipcode)' ,4,3),
 ('delete FROM country' ,7,1),
 ('delete FROM zipcode' ,6,4)
--- you can change below code to proc  u can write case statements if u want only inset or delete like that
DECLARE @outtable table(statements varchar(200),seqno int,id int iDENTITY(1,1))
INSERT INTO @outtable
SELECT  statements,seqno FROM @table WHERE statements like '%insert%' ORDER BY seqno   ASC
INSERT INTO @outtable
SELECT  statements,seqno FROM @table WHERE statements like '%update%' ORDER BY seqno ASC
INSERT INTO @outtable
SELECT  statements,seqno FROM @table WHERE statements like '%delete%' ORDER BY seqno     DESC
SELECT   * FROM @outtable order by id asc
```